# Is it possible to print the decision tree in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to print a trained decision tree in scikit-learn? I want to train a decision tree for my thesis and I want to put the picture of the tree in the thesis. Is that possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a method to export to graph_viz format: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html

So from the online docs:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn import tree
>>>
>>> clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>>
>>> clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
>>> tree.export_graphviz(clf,
...     out_file='tree.dot')
```

Then you can load this using graph viz, or if you have pydot installed then you can do this more directly: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

```
>>> from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
>>> import pydot 
>>> dot_data = StringIO() 
>>> tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
>>> graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
>>> graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Will produce an svg, can't display it here so you'll have to follow the link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/iris.svg

**Update**

It seems that there has been a change in the behaviour since I first answered this question and it now returns a `list` and hence you get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'
```

Firstly when you see this it's worth just printing the object and inspecting the object, and most likely what you want is the first object:

```
graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Thanks to @NickBraunagel for the comment

Comment: I get this error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'` How can I resolve this?

Comment: @EdChum can you kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880557/how-to-print-and-visualize-the-average-randomforestclassifier-of-all-trees-for-a

Comment: @ErnestSoo (and anyone else running into your error: `pydot.graph_from_dot_data()` returns the desired `graph` (the `pydot.Dot` object) but it returns it within a `list`: so, access the list's first object to access the `pydot.Dot` object: `graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")`

Comment: @NickBraunagel as it seems a lot of people are getting this error I will add this as an update, it looks like this is some change in behaviour since I answered this question over 3 years ago, thanks

Comment: how would you do the same thing but on test data?

Answer (score 9):

Although I'm late to the game, the below comprehensive instructions could be useful for others who want to display decision tree output:

Install necessary modules:

1. install `graphviz`.  I used conda's install package [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz)
   (recommended over `pip install graphviz` as `pip` install doesn't
   include the actual GraphViz [executables](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/))
2. install `pydot` via pip (`pip install pydot`)
3. Add the graphviz folder directory containing the .exe files (e.g. dot.exe) to your environment variable PATH
4. run EdChum's above (NOTE: `graph` is a `list` containing the `pydot.Dot` object):

---

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydot 

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 

graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")  # must access graph's first element
```

Now you'll find the "iris.pdf" within your environment's default directory

Answer (score 7):

There are 4 methods which I'm aware of for plotting the scikit-learn decision tree:

- print the text representation of the tree with `sklearn.tree.export_text` method
- plot with `sklearn.tree.plot_tree` method (`matplotlib` needed)
- plot with `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` method (`graphviz` needed)
- plot with `dtreeviz` package (`dtreeviz` and `graphviz` needed)

The simplest is to export to the text representation. The example decision tree will look like:

```
|--- feature_2 <= 2.45
|   |--- class: 0
|--- feature_2 >  2.45
|   |--- feature_3 <= 1.75
|   |   |--- feature_2 <= 4.95
|   |   |   |--- feature_3 <= 1.65
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |   |--- feature_3 >  1.65
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 2
|   |   |--- feature_2 >  4.95
|   |   |   |--- feature_3 <= 1.55
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 2
|   |   |   |--- feature_3 >  1.55
|   |   |   |   |--- feature_0 <= 6.95
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |   |   |--- feature_0 >  6.95
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 2
|   |--- feature_3 >  1.75
|   |   |--- feature_2 <= 4.85
|   |   |   |--- feature_1 <= 3.10
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 2
|   |   |   |--- feature_1 >  3.10
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |--- feature_2 >  4.85
|   |   |   |--- class: 2
```

Then if you have `matplotlib` installed, you can plot with `sklearn.tree.plot_tree`:

```py
tree.plot_tree(clf) # the clf is your decision tree model
```

The example output is similar to what you will get with `export_graphviz`:
[image: sklearn decision tree visualization]

You can also try [`dtreeviz`](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/tree/master/dtreeviz) package. It will give you much more information. The example:

[image: dtreeviz example decision tree]

You can find a comparison of different visualization of sklearn decision tree with code snippets in this blog post: [link](https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-decision-tree/).