# Using graphviz to plot decision tree in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pydot

I am following the answer presented to a previous post: [Is it possible to print the decision tree in scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274673/is-it-possible-to-print-the-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydot

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
tree.export_graphviz(clf,    out_file='tree.dot')
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the following error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'write_pdf'
```

Does anyone know a way around this as the structure of the generated `tree.dot` file is a list?

**Update**

I have attempted using the web application http://webgraphviz.com/. This works, however, the decision tree conditions, together with the classes are not displayed. Is there any way to include these in the `tree.dot` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like data that you collect in `graph` is of type `list`.

```
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
type(graph)
<type 'list'>
```

We are only interested in first element of the list.
So you can do this one of following of two ways,

1) Change line where you collect `dot_data` value in `graph` to

```
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
```

2) Or collect entire list in `graph` but just use first element to be sent to `pdf`

```
graph[0].write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Here is what I get as output of *iris.pdf*

[image]
**Update**

To get around path error,

> Exception: "dot.exe" not found in path.

Install `graphviz` from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php)

Then use either following in your code.

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Or simply add following to your windows path in control panel.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin

As per  `graphviz` documentation, it does not get added to windows path during installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had been playing around with similar solutions but am left with the error ""dot.exe" not found in path." From reading around, I am thinking that this error is due to my installation of Graphiz?

Comment: Please see my edits for path error. if this solves your problem do consider accepting as answer to close the loop.